# python flask ImportError: No module named views.login

Tags: python, flask

I have a app named `flaskr`. When I want to import views.login` from views. it gives me error:

```
   File "C:\Projects\flaskr\flaskr.py", line 28, in <module>
     from flaskr.views.login import login
ImportError: No module named views.login
```

Before I put all the methods inside the `flaskr.py` file. I want to move each functions to different views, like login, show_entries, log_out, just like MVC has different views.

flaskr.py

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

from flaskr.views.login import login
app.register_blueprint(login)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

login.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

login = Blueprint('login', __name__,template_folder='../template')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: Do you have your folders set up as modules correctly? You need `__init__.py` files in the module folders to import. You'll also have an issue in login.py. You need to change the name of either the blueprint folder `login` or the function `login` to something else.

Comment: we need your directory structure and the files also? you can try by creating an empty `__init__.py` file in each directory where it is used as modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create folder named app or whatever. 
Create `__init__.py` file in app:

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

from app import views

app.register_blueprint(views.login)
```

Move app.run method into separate start.py file in root directory

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Create folder views in app/. Create `__init__.py` in views
Now you could have structure like this:

```
your_project_name/
    |app/
    |__init__.py            
        |views/
            |__init__.py
            |login.py
    start.py
```

Sorry, if there are have mistakes.

Comment: By the way, it's typical Flask app folder structure.